# Compute. $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm a math student going over some old exam questions. I have arrived at a number of questions that ask me to compute the limit of a function near a given number (2 in this case). But they appear to be harder than I first realised.

$$\frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2} = \frac{1- \frac{4}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{2}{x^2}} \iff \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1- \frac{4}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{2}{x^2}}= \frac{1-1}{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{0}{0} $$

Even though I used the algebra of limits I still arrived at a division of zero. I feel I have made a rookie mistake or assumption, but if anyone can help me fill the hole in my logic that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your last step where you got $(1-1)/(1/2-1/2)$ is wrong. The laws of limits don't work in case of quotient when the denominator tends to $0$. Those limit laws work only with the hypotheses stated with them.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2}=\lim_{x \to 2} (x+2)=4$$

Comment: the question is $lim_{x \to 2}$.the answer should be 4

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to use a technique meant for $x\to\infty$, which is irrelevant here. (In this technique, the terms with negative powers of $x$ can be discarded as they become negligible. But here, they don't.)

In the case on hand, you can use that

$$\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=x+2$$ for all $x\ne2$.

---

Interestingly, you can reduce this problem to a limit at infinity by setting $x:=2+\dfrac1t$ and

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\left(2+\dfrac1t\right)^2-4}{2+\dfrac1t-2}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac4t+\dfrac1{t^2}}{\dfrac1t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{4+\dfrac1t}1.$$